# how to edit the width of menu bar in dreamweaver

Tags: css, dreamweaver, menubar

any one can give me a quick indication.
I am trying to create a menu bar on my website, but after put it on, don't know how to edit the website, and it show on dreamweaver is different show on the website after I upload it online. and I tried to edit the css file which can't change the width as well.

please check the image that on the website here:
http://www.xuanyinwen.com/images/temp/test.jpg

and on dreamweaver:
http://www.xuanyinwen.com/images/temp/test1.jpg

Thank you very much for your time

Wayne

Comment: You definitely have to provide (some of) the code in order for us to help you.

Comment: You're using a product that was released something like 7 years ago (and is now 4 versions old with CS3, CS4, and CS5 coming after it), and the rendering engine had to be baked into the app prior to that. There have been significant improvements in the Design View rendering of CSS since then, as well as the newer Live View added in CS4 that uses a WebKit rendering engine to allow you to see your design more as a browser will see it (and as Diodeus says), even with that, there are still plenty of other browsers that will show some things differently.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. will update it when I got enough money then. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamweaver is not a dependable tool for previewing HTML. Always preview it in the browser.

Dreamweaver will give you an approximate representation, but it will never be 100% accurate, especially when it comes to how your page will look in **different browsers**. It can't possibly represent three different rendering engines at the same time.

Comment: Nothing can represent Trident. Not even IE.